# Firebase hosting causing insecure connection via www

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I'm using firebase hosting for my website. If I visit my website by typing just the domain in the address bar (eg example.com) or https://example.com, it works fine. However, if I were to add a prefix www (eg www.example.com or https://example.com), then I get an insecure connection error. Is there any way to fix this? Thanks

Comment: having the same issue currently, I think its a bug.

Comment: Did you *just* register the domain with Firebase? If so, there is a message on the Firebase console that says it may take 20 minutes for that message to disappear. If it's been more than a few hours, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Comment: Have you added both example.com and www.example.com to your site in the Firebase Console? You must explicitly add each domain and subdomain.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I just realised that you have to add both example.com and www.example.com to your site in the Firebase Console.

Thanks