# Why We can't Access Firebase hosted site with www

Tags: firebase, web, firebase-hosting

Why i can't  access the firebase hosted site with the www prefix if I remove www From there it works.

Check this demo site :--

https://www.fir-demo-project.web.app : Not working ❎

https://fir-demo-project.web.app  : Working ✅

Comment: You need to check your DNS settings

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Hosting simply does not provide a free www address for your site.  According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/test-preview-deploy#view-changes), here is what you get for free:

> The Firebase-provisioned subdomains for your default Hosting site and
> any additional Hosting sites:
>
> - SITE_ID.web.app (like PROJECT_ID.web.app)
> - SITE_ID.firebaseapp.com (like PROJECT_ID.firebaseapp.com)

If you want to customize the domain for your site, you need to register a domain and [configure Firebase Hosting to use that](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain).  You can then control the domain any way you like.

Answer (score -1):

To redirect [www.fir-demo-project.web.app](http://www.fir-demo-project.web.app)  to fir-demo-project.web.app  then you need to add CNAME record.

To redirect fir-demo-project.web.app to [www.fir-demo-project.web.app](http://www.fir-demo-project.web.app), you need to add A record.

Kindly check your DNS entries for the domain

Comment: so its not possible with free firebase domain , Right?

Comment: @DixitRam sorry for make you confuse, just add the CNAME to DNS provider of your firebase project

Comment: its a default url given by firbase and with its base Url of web.app , so I think I cant add CNAME!!

Comment: @DixitRam Just find out that your domain is working normally, just www host was unsecured. To resolve it, find the answer in an old thread here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42186130/firebase-hosting-causing-insecure-connection-via-www

Comment: Access your Firebase console hosting and add a custom domain with the hostname www.fir-demo-project.web.app|

Comment: i dont own web.app so i cant redirect it. Web.app is from firebase. its like projectName.Web.app default by firebase. BTW thanks For Helping me and Sorry To irritet you I am new to firebase –

Comment: Yah, I knew, The hosting page is in your Firebase console, i.e my project hosting link https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/proximity-ecf97/hosting/sites

Just access your firebase console and Add a custom domain to the hosting page

Comment: so i need to buy custom  domain.i cant add www  to projectname.web.app